# How to define an idempotent consumer in Apache Camel YAML DSL using a combination of headers?

Tags: yaml, apache-camel, dsl

I am using the Camel Main component version 3.19 with the following YAML DSL route to successfully load files from an AWS/S3 bucket to the local file system:

```
- beans:
    - name: IdempotentRepositoryBean
      type: org.apache.camel.support.processor.idempotent.MemoryIdempotentRepository

- route:
    from:
      uri: "aws2-s3:arn:aws:s3:someBucket"
      parameters:
        # The AWS region hosting the bucket and the access credentials
        # are obtained from Properties file.
        amazonS3Client: "#awss3SourceClient"
        deleteAfterRead: "false"
      steps:
        - idempotent-consumer:
            idempotent-repository: "IdempotentRepositoryBean"
            header: "CamelAwsS3Key"
            skip-duplicate: true
        - set-header:
            name: "CamelFileName"
            simple: "${header.CamelAwsS3Key}"
        - to:
            uri: "file:C:/..."
```

However, in addition to the header `CamelAwsS3Key` I also want to include the header `CamelAwsS3LastModified` in order to enforce that files renewed on S3 while this route is running are not skipped.
Using an equivalent route in Java DSL and appending the key `CamelAwsS3LastModified` as shown below works fine:

```
   route = from(fromEndpoint).
             idempotentConsumer(header("CamelAwsS3Key").
                  append(header("CamelAwsS3LastModified")), idempotentRepository);
```

How can I define the combined `header` as part of the `idempotent-consumer` spec in the same way in the YAML DSL route above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that what you are trying to do is not possible with the YAML DSL, as workaround, you can replace your expression with the corresponding [simple expression](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/languages/simple-language.html), something like:

```
...
    - idempotent-consumer:
        idempotent-repository: "IdempotentRepositoryBean"
        simple: "${header.CamelAwsS3Key}${header.CamelAwsS3LastModified}"
        skip-duplicate: true
...
```